# Safecracker Registration Return path url issue

Tags: templates, safecracker, members, matrix, safecracker-registration

I have confused myself slightly setting up the return path for my safecracker login form for the following site [Click here for link][1]

*if you scroll down to the roster section click mel debarge, in the the pop up you will notice a download section, when you click on the press kit button you are redirected to the login page.*

When user enter the correct login detail they are able to access a PDF/JPEG which i have uploaded in the Matrix i have set up. The parameters for the matrix are the following `{press_material}{press_pdf}{press_material}`

In the entry properties for my login form i have the following:

```
{exp:safecracker
channel="roster"
    dynamic_title="[member_first_name] [member_last_name]"
    include_jquery="no"
    group_id="5"
    loggin_member="yes"
    error_handling="inline"
    return="{path='{press_material}{press_pdf}{/press_material}/{url_title}'}"
```

In aim to redirect registered users to the file uploaded in the matrix, However i don't seem to be having any joy. Does anyone know how i can resolve this issue??

do i need to use the embed proporties in order for this to work?

[1]:

Comment: Does this work with a hardcoded URL based on what you are trying to accomplish with the tags?

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl i'm trying to work out a url...

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking if you've tried hard coding a URL that should work as a test.

Comment: yes. Hard coding the URL, works fine

Comment: Okay. Sounds like something isn't parsing correctly then. Try overriding the return="" parameter inside the safecracker tag using: <input type="hidden" value="{path='{press_material}{press_pdf}{/press_material}/{url_title}" name="return"> OR <input type="hidden" value="/{press_material}{press_pdf}{/press_material}/{url_title}" name="return">

Comment: Hmmm. for some reason that method doesn't work.

Comment: When you inspect the html what do you see? Is the hidden input field printing out the correct return URL?

Comment: it gives me an empty body on the login page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7754/discussion-between-anna-mediagirl-and-newboy)

Comment: Can you post the page code at Gist, https://gist.github.com, Pastebin or here. Obviously, obscure anything you need to. But it looks like, you are trying to do two things. Get someone to login, then have them redirect. They need to login before the redirect, and you're not delivering a login form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this was twofold:

1. Needed to add register_member="yes" to the Safecracker Registration tag
2. {url_title} wasn't being parsed as coded. Changing the tag to {segment_3} got the return path working correctly.